# Absolute positioned element not showing with top z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

As part of my site there is a search field which features a suggestion/autocomplete box when the user types in current keywords. [image](https://www.webdeveloper.com/assets/files/2020-04-20/1587361949-61507-image.png)

The problem is in order to make a scroll bar appear if the user types in too much i have to set overflow-x to auto and overflow-y to hidden. This then results in the suggestion box not showing/being cutoff by the overflow-y.
[image](https://i.ibb.co/M5p3Zy2/image.png)

You can find a demo of the issue here: 
http://testing.server-lists.com/minecraft/

A codepen simplified example can be found [here](https://codepen.io/jiak1/pen/bGVwpEv)`As stackoverflow limited me to 3000 characters.`

Even though the suggestions box has absolute positioning and a 1000 z index it is not appearing, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the demo site you referred to and just removed the style attributes:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

From the div with class="bootstrap-tagsinput" and remove white-space:no-wrap;
as it is almost impossible to show any thing if it is wrapped in a container has an overflow hidden.

Can you try it please and tell me if this works?

Comment: Unfortunatley this then removes the scrolling behaviour which i want to keep, otherwise typing goes off the edge. Wouls you know how to still have the scroll bar with it positioned properly?

Comment: Hello, I think you can fix this if you set the element with class (**twitter-typeahead**) to be positioned static:

   `.twitter-typeahead {
        position:static !important;
    }`